# Vagrant & Maven Plugin strange behaviour

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, vagrant

I've set up a Vagrant VM running Java/Maven/Tomcat. I've then taken an application I'm working on and copied the war to the shared folder that the VM has access to, namely webapps. I hunted around as didn't want to be copy / pasting when it should be automated and found reference to a maven plugin:

```
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Username/Development/temp/vagrant-tomcat-2/vagrant-ubuntu-tomcat7/tomcat/webapps</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

I've added this to my build. Made a simple change to the index and ran clean install. My console panel looks as I'd expect it to, the war is being copied across - magic.

```
[INFO] Installing Username/Development/temp/vagrant-tomcat-2/vagrant-

ubuntu-tomcat7/tomcat/webapps/FitnessTracker.war to Username/.m2/repository/com/pluralsight/FitnessTracker/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/FitnessTracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing Username/Development/temp/vagrant-tomcat-2/Spring Tutorial - JPA Hibernate/spring_mvc_base-master/pom.xml to Username/.m2/repository/com/pluralsight/FitnessTracker/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/FitnessTracker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

I then reload the port and get a resource is not available error.  Commenting out the plugin and running clean install again has the effect of copying the last changes I made to the webapp folder so that If I then check the port I'll see the changes.

What am I missing? I'm certain it's something daft.

The short short version: the maven plugin appears to be copying the last updated war instead of the current one, I think.